# What sort algorithm does PHP use?

Tags: php, algorithm

Internally speaking, which algorithm(s) does PHP use to implement the various sort functions it offers? It seems like the usort variants might use a different algorithm than the built in sorts, but I wanted to know.

Where would I even find this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could find the information by looking at the php manual. http://php.net/sort says PHP uses an implementation of [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). Failing that, you could always trudge through the PHP source code itself.

Answer (score 22):

For sorting, PHP uses an implementation of quicksort that can be found in [`Zend/zend_sort.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_sort.c), which takes a comparison function and an array of elements. The default comparison function for `sort()` is defined in [`ext/standard/array.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L362) and is called `php_array_data_compare()`. So basically, it's the same algorithm for *all* sorting functions, except that they take different comparison functions.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, PHP uses quick sort

Comment: Since Timothy "ninja'ed" you in the FGITW game, and because this 5-word answer isn't found to be helpful by any researchers in over a decade, you might entertain the idea of dropping this post from the page.  Your call.