# Is this algorithm faster then php sort()?

Tags: php

Is my algorithm faster then php sort() ?

algo:

```
        $a = array(0,3,4,2,7,6,6,8,6,1);
        $z = count($a)-1;
        for($i = 0;$i < $z; $i++){
           if($a[$i] > $a[$i+1]){
              $temp = $a[$i];
              $a[$i] = $a[$i+1];
              $a[$i+1] = $temp;
              $i = -1;
           }   
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($a);
        echo "</pre>";
```

compare with php sort() ... let me know your results as i have bad internet...

Comment: No it's not. This is not a place where people will compare your code to native PHP methods and give you results.

Comment: Why is `$i` an array? You never use anything other than `$i[0]`.

Comment: Of course, interpreted PHP code is always faster than optimized and compiled C binary.

Comment: Your algorithm looks like [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Comment: well i used microtime and my algo was faster on my pc ... this is why i am asking ... to see if i did not get fake results.

Comment: @alin100 Try sorting an array with a million elements and see how they compare.

Comment: You know that you don't need internet access to run a sorting algorithm, right? And also no, a userland implementation of bubble sort is not going to be faster than the language's own method.

Comment: $i[0] is to reset for loop when it finds 4 ,2

Comment: @iainn did you compare it to say that sort() is faster then that algo ?

Comment: Compare and prove that is slower then sort(); this is what i am asking . Thank you !

Comment: @alin100 But why is it `$i[0]` and `$z[0]` instead of just `$i` and `$z`? These variables don't need to be arrays, just ordinary variables.

Comment: it didn't reset $i do to unknown reason and i changed it to $i[0] ,worked with $i[0],if i do $i instead of $i[0] i get like a infinite loop  ... white screen

Comment: @Barmar if i change $z[0] to $z i get white screen and page loading forever ...

Comment: You also have to change to `$z = count($a) - 1;` so it's not put into an unnecessary array.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for noticing that ... it solved that $z and $i thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in [What sort algorithm does PHP use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165984/what-sort-algorithm-does-php-use), the built-in sorting algorithm is [Quicksort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165984/what-sort-algorithm-does-php-use#:%7E:text=For%20sorting%2C%20PHP%20uses%20an,in%20ext%2Fstandard%2Farray.). The average performance of Quicksort is O(n log n).

Your algorithm is similar to [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). Its average performance is O(n<sup>2</sup>). But since your code goes back to the beginning after each swap, which is unnecessary, it's even worse than bubble sort.

For large arrays, Quicksort will be significantly faster than Bubble Sort.

Also, the `sort()` function is implemented in C code, which is compiled to machine code. Using a sorting algorithm written in PHP will have additional overhead of the PHP interpreter.

You also have a number of unnecesary arrays `$i` and `$z`, which should just be ordinary variables.

```
$a = array(0,3,4,2,7,6,6,8,6,1);
$z = count($a)-1;
for($i = 0;$i < $z; $i++){
    if($a[$i] > $a[$i+1]){
        $temp = $a[$i];
        $a[$i] = $a[$i+1];
        $a[$i+1] = $temp;
        $i = -1;
    }   
}
```

Comment: thank you for seeing that i  changed it ...

Comment: in bubble sort https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort  i noticed that it does not reset once you make switch of 2 value,it goes to the end of array ... in my code when you switch / flip values , it goes back to 0 and starts over ... it's a variation of bubble sort ...

Comment: That probably makes your algorithm worse, since there' no need to go back to the beginning.

Comment: who knows we may find a use for it one day :)